# What does "get passes" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Clinton **gets passes** for everything.

Source: [Trump voters stay loyal: 'I am not voting for him to be pope'](http://money.cnn.com/2016/10/09/news/economy/voting-for-donald-trump/index.html?iid=Lead) on CNN Money US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "pass" in the sense of the OED's **pass** *n* 4, definition 7g:

> g. An explicit or implicit permission, licence, or authorization to
>   engage in something without (legal) conditions or restrictions. Freq.
>   in negative contexts.

So "gets passes for everything" means "is permitted to do everything", or more specifically, "is not restricted or censured for anything".

Comment: In other words, imagine I illegally cross the street in order to pull a child out of traffic.  A police officer who sees me break the law in order to help a child might decide I should not be punished.  This is called "getting a pass", or "letting it slide".  In this example, I get a pass because the police officer supports my actions.  In your example, Clinton gets a pass for political reasons.

Comment: @MikeKozar: yes, but I dont think I'd ever use the phrase "getting a pass" in that sort of case where there is a genuine violation. It's more in the vague metaphorical sense of political life.

Answer (score 0):

There, "gets passes" means "is not held accountable".